# How to Insert image in my computer using html & Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, version-control, html5-canvas

How to Insert image in my computer using html & Angular

<img src="assets/images/img.png"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the path root-relative:

```html
<img src="/assets/images/img.png" />
```